# Is there a guarantee that all exploded rows in a stream will get updated into table at once?

Tags: ksqldb

If I have a stream **s1** with `messages` column of type `Array<Map<VARCHAR, VARCHAR>>` like below

```
ROWTIME    key   messages
-------------------------------
t1          1     [{id: 1, k1: v1, k2: v2}, {id: 2, k1: v3, k2: v4}]
t2          2     [{id: 1, k1: v5, k2: v6}, {id: 2, k1: v7, k2: v8}]
.......
.......
```

I am creating another stream **s2** using

```
create stream s2 as select explode(message) from s1 emit changes;
```

```
ROWTIME           message
-----------------------------
t1              {id: 1, k1: v1, k2: v2}
t1              {id: 2, k1: v3, k2: v4}
t2              {id: 1, k1: v5, k2: v6}
t2              {id: 2, k1: v7, k2: v8}
...........
...........
```

My aim is to create a table with `id`, `k1`, `k2` columns, I am publishing in array format in **s1** to make sure that they both are updated in table together.

```
create stream s3 as select message['id'] as id, message['k1'] as k1, message['k2'] as k2 from s2 emit changes;
```

```
create table table1 as select id, latest_by_offset(k1), latest_by_offset(k2) from s3 group by id emit changes;
```

With above, is there any guarantee that all the messages (with any count, currently count is 2) which are exploded from a single array will get applied to table 1 at once? In other words is there a guarantee that below state is **never** possible, with only id `1` from `t2` timestamp is applied on `table 1` but id `2` from `t2` timestamp is not applied.

```
ROWTIME       id        k1          k2
----------------------------------------
t1             2        v3          v4
t2             1        v5          v6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently guaranteed by ksqlDB. Though it is potentially possible to enhance ksqlDB to support this. Probably worth raising a [feature request](https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues/new/choose).