# Atomicity across the keys in ksqlDB Table

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I wanted to know if there is any way to achieve the atomicity across the keys in ksqlDB table? So basically my use case is that I am receiving multiple messages on kafka topic and I want to apply them on table atomically so that materialised view is consistent so for example take an use case where I am storing the hierarchy in ksqlDB table in sparse format:

[image]

Now let's assume k1 and k2 is the composite key of table and on kafka topic following two messages are published:

```
{k1: k11, k2: 'All', v1: v111, v2: v211}, 
{k1: k11, k2: k21, v1: v121, v2: v221}
```

and now I want to make sure that these messages are applied on ksqlDB table atomically i.e either both of the messages are applied or none of them are applied so that my table is always consistent - is it possible to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is probably, no.

I'm not really following your example of sparse format given in table 1.  Care to explain?

ksqlDB process and applies each received event individually. It does not have any mechanism to atomically apply multiple events.

I'm not aware of any streaming engine that could atomically apply two events. Streams are, by definition, infinite. How would an engine known which events need to be applied atomically and which don't?

If you can produce all updates that must be applied atomically together in a single message, then this is something that ksqlDB could potentially support applying atomically in the future via the use of `EXPLODE`, as suggested here: [Is there a guarantee that all exploded rows in a stream will get updated into table at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749698/is-there-a-guarantee-that-all-exploded-rows-in-a-stream-will-get-updated-into-ta/63160979#63160979).